# How to remove dynamically created audio element in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, createelement

Every 30 seconds I refresh a script to check for changes. The returned data sets the src for an audio element.

If the data has changed, I change the src attribute to match, but onClick - I hear **both** audio files play together.

What's happening here and how can I remove the previous audio file?

```
(function fetchCal() {
$.getJSON('events', function(data) {

//I need to clear any previously created elements here

  var nowAudio = document.createElement('audio');
  nowAudio.setAttribute('src',"audio/"+data.uid+"."+data.nowTitleURL+".mp3" );

  $('.now').click(function() {
      nowAudio.play();
  });

})
setTimeout(fetchCal, 30000); //refresh calendar every 30 secs
})();
```

note:  `$( "audio" ).remove();` didn't work

Comment: What do you mean by "remove"? It is not added to the DOM so why should it be removed?

Comment: The issue is more like you are binding click events and not removing the previous click event....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding multiple clcicks to the same element so it will always have the previous click events. You would need to unbind it.

```
$('.now').off("click.audio").on("click.audio", function() {
  nowAudio.play();
});
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!! I was recently having issues with my code same as the original question and your answer solved the issue!! Thanks again :)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how to remove the previous elements though.

Comment: It did answer the question 6 years ago. The event was bound multiple times. The OP was not removing the element, they were just changing the source. Yes the OP could have reused the same audio element which would have made this moot.